# Painting outside Paintcomponent?

Tags: paintcomponent

I am developing a game using Java. Currently I am painting all of my graphics in my paintcomponent class. But this means that everytime I want to repaint small details (like move a cloud or swap out a picture). I have to repaint the entire screen. This takes up a lot of memory. Is there some way that I can paint outside of my paint component to make my game more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

you can use repaint(i,i1,i2,i3) to repaint only the area you mention.see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)